# How can I get the contents of an std::string into a CFData object?

Tags: c++, cocoa, core-graphics, cgimage, cfdata

I've got a [function](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/common/base64.html) that returns a `std::string` object. I'm working with Cocoa/CoreGraphics and I need a way to get the data from that string into a `CFData` [object](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFDataRef/Reference/reference.html) so that I can feed *that* into a `CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData` [object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261177/cgimage-from-byte-array/2261343#2261343) to make a `CGImage`.

The `CreateCFData` function wants a `const UInt8*` object (`UInt8` being a typedef for `unsigned char`). The string represents the bytes from a decoded Base64 string (image data), so it appears to contain many null "characters" so the obvious casting of the `.c_str()` output to an `unsigned char*` object won't work.

I'm less experienced with C++ and very new to Cocoa/CoreGraphics, so if there's a much better way to accomplish what I'm wanting to do please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CFDataCreate( NULL, (const UInt8*) myString.data(), myString.size() )`