# How to get CGImageRef from C++ base64 byte string image

Tags: c++, objective-c, uiimage, cgimage

Maybe I need to scale down my question to something a little more simple.

> How do I get the byte string into a CGImageRef ?

Here, I am using a CFDataRef and a CGDataProviderRef.  Maybe there is a better way?

---

I am receiving a base64 encoded image as a std::string.  Now I need to stuff it back into a CGImageRef to get the data back into the correct format to populate a UIImage.  **If the data is not in the correct format the UIImage will be nil.**

I've been looking for how to do this for days now and I cannot seem to figure this out.  Here is my code for trying to convert the image:

```
- (UIImage *)testProcessedImage:(std::string)byteString
{
    CFDataRef dataRef = CFDataCreate( NULL, (const UInt8*) byteString.data(), byteString.length() );
    CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(dataRef);

    // Code below does not appear to work
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWith ....... ;  // Maybe ?
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    UIImage *image3 = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:(__bridge CGImageRef)(image)];
    return image3;
}
```

There is a lot of code out there that has helped me get to this point but I'm stuck.  **The above code returns nil** and I cannot figure out how to get it right.

---

If anybody wants to test this, here is the code that takes a UIImage and simulates the server-side code by converting the image into a std::string.  Thanks in advance for your help.

---

```
- (UIImage *)testChangeImageToBase64String
{
    UIImage *processedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myFile.jpg"];

    // UIImage to unsigned char *
    CGImageRef imageRef = processedImage.CGImage;
    NSData *data1 = (NSData *) CFBridgingRelease(CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(imageRef)));

    //UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    unsigned char *pixels = (unsigned char *)[data1 bytes];
    unsigned long size = [data1 length];

    // ***************************************************************************
    // This is where we would call transmit and receive the bytes in a std::string
    // ***************************************************************************

    // unsigned char * to string
    const std::string byteString(pixels, pixels + size);

    UIImage *newImage = [self testProcessedImage:byteString];
    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: I think the main issue with this is you're expecting a constant data representation from UIImage.  The framework makes no such guarantee.  Perhaps a more direct route (`+[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:]`) would be a better idea.

Comment: The closest information to what I am trying to do is in this question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/2261177/1735836), except I am not dealing with a byte array.  I have a byte string.  I'm not sure how to use dataWithContentsOfFile for this purpose.  Here's another question that is similar (http://stackoverflow.com/q/3764512/1735836).  Thank you.

Comment: Could this be the answer?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/24899398/1735836