# Objective C, base64 png to UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, base64, data-uri

I'm trying to convert a data:image/png;base64 to an UIImage, then get a CGImage and from the UIImage and send it to a Zebra printer.

I try this code:

```
NSData *datad = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataFromBase64String:@"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS...etc"]];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:datad];
[image CGIamge]
```

And i'm trying with this code:

```
NSString *base64Url = @"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS...etc";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:base64Url];
NSString *base64Image = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url];
url = [NSURL URLWithString:base64Image];
NSData *rawImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:rawImageData];
```

With the second part of the code i get a black image.

I'm doing something wrong for sure.

I'm also try to do this [How to create CGImageRef from NSData string data (NOT UIImage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898125/how-to-create-cgimageref-from-nsdata-string-data-not-uiimage)

aaaaand nothing.

Please, if someone could help me, you will be my heroe!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove that `data:image/png;base64,` prefix, and only include the actual base64 payload (including any `=` characters at the end) when you call `dataFromBase64String`.

Comment: Thanks, it seems the printer configuration, the image was created fine, I even save to album.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:strEncodeData options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems the printer configuration, the image was created fine, I even save to album.